# Why i'm getting out of memory exception and how should i avoid it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my program i'm capturing a screenshot of the destop window each second using a timer:
The exception message is:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
       at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
       at CapturedDesktop.Form1.screenshots(String filename) in d:\C-Sharp\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\Form1.cs:line 53
       at CapturedDesktop.Form1.CaptureScreenshot() in d:\C-Sharp\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\Form1.cs:line 31
       at CapturedDesktop.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\Form1.cs:line 63
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at CapturedDesktop.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\CapturedDesktop\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The exception is on the line:

```
bmpScreenshot.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif);
```

It was savig fine to the hard disk the images untill file number 000110 that's mean the program was working fine for 110 seconds and then the exception came up.

Maybe i should dispose the bmp variable somewhere ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using unfreez_wrapper;

namespace CapturedDesktop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int screens;
        string gifsdirectory;
        UnFreezWrapper unfreez;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            unfreez = new UnFreezWrapper();
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            screens = 0;
            gifsdirectory = @"C:\Temp\CapturedDesktop\";
        }


        private void CaptureScreenshot()
        {
            screens++;
            screenshots(gifsdirectory + screens.ToString("D6") + ".gif");
        }

        public static void screenshots(string filename)
        {
            //Create a new bitmap.
            var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
            var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

            // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
            bmpScreenshot.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureScreenshot();
        }

        private void AnimatedGifButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> myGifList = new List<string>();
            FileInfo[] fi;
            DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(gifsdirectory);
            fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");
            for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
            {
                myGifList.Add(fi[i].FullName);
            }
            unfreez.MakeGIF(myGifList, gifsdirectory + "agif", 100, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `that's mean the program was working fine for 110 seconds and then the exception came up.` - Does that mean it took around 110 seconds to try save the file?

Comment: SemiDemented what file ? It means that it took 110 seconds to save the 110 files . 000110 is the last file the first file is 000000.gif the timer interval is 1000ms. I meant that it took 110 seconds to save all the files untill 000110 and then after file 000110.gif which is 110 seconds instead creating 000111.gif it was showing the exception.

Comment: Yes, you certainly should dispose of your bitmaps. The out of memory exception is a dead giveaway. And one question per question! Stackoverflow is not a forum. Read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After saving the Image, You need to `Dispose` it. Otherwise you push all the responsibility to GC. GC can sometimes save you, sometimes not.

Given that Image size is equal to screen size, which means that memory taken by the image will also be huge. You ought to Dispose it as soon as you don't need it.

```
public static void screenshots(string filename)
{
    //Create a new bitmap.
    using( var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                   PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
        using(var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
        {

            // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }
        // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
        bmpScreenshot.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```

Prefer [using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to `Dispose` a disposable resource.

Comment: And also the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), though that's less important.

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I added that also. It's not less important. It is important. There are only [maximum of 65,536 gdi objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can create. You should release previous allocations to create more.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel calling dispose is a good practice but not mandatory, as you suggested GC will invariably come in the picture and it does a pretty good cleaning job, in such cases various other factors come in, like object above is local, so it up for collection quickly. In such cases frequency of object creation, memory settings like 3GB (32 bit) and even explicit GC calls like GC.Collect, GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers can save the day, would give enough time for GC reduce the overall memory pressure